# Problems mounting and dumping to external storage (Mac) from dedicated server (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, osx, dd, sshfs

I have set up a Kimsufi KS-4A - 16G i7-920 1x2TB Server, and been following [this guide](https://joodle.nl/how-to-create-your-own-windows-template-for-kimsufi/) on how to create my own Windows template for Kimsufi. I have come to the last steps of the tutorial.

What I want to do at this point is to use Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, which I have mounted and running from an ISO on my server via Proxmox, to create and dump the Windows template (also on the same server) to my Mac computer as I don't have a second VPS or server.

When I do `root@ubuntu:~# sudo sshfs root@84.211.114.77:/home /mnt/temp`
I get the error `read: Connection reset by peer`. I have done `root@ubuntu:~# mkdir /mnt/temp` and `root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install sshfs`. I have also installed OSXFuse and SSHFS 2.5.0 on my Mac and enabled the root user. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Okay. I went into Terminal on my Mac's root user and did this: `Bjorns-MacBook-Pro:~ root# apt-get install ssh` `-sh: apt-get: command not found`
`Bjorns-MacBook-Pro:~ root# /etc/ssh/sshd_config` `-sh: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied`.

Do I have to install macOS server in order for my Mac to be able to act as one? Bear in mind that I am a complete noob and may lack elementary understanding of what needs to be done beforehand in order for this to work. If it's too much of a hassle, I just ordered a web server with SSH-support, but still waiting for my domain to get transferred.

Comment: Alright, I managed to figure it all out within a week, without knowing Linux at all. I borrowed a web server with SSH-support, and did this `user@ubuntu:~# sudo -i` `root@ubuntu:~# mkdir /mnt/temp` `root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install sshfs` `root@ubuntu:~# ssh-keygen -t dsa` `eval $(ssh-agent)` `ssh-agent bash` `ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_dsa` `apt-get install libgnome2-bin` `gnome-open /root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` (to paste the key into the server) `sudo sshfs username@xxx.xxx.xx:/home/xxx /mnt/temp -pxxxxx -o nonempty` `dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 | dd of=/mnt/temp/WindowsTemplate.gz`. Thanks for nothing!